# Generating random letters from a-z

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that will make a sequence of random letters from a-z. For some reason though it doesn't work, and it prints other symbols too. i know there is an issue on how i use puts, since there is not only one sequence but "size" of them, but i did it just to check that the letter generator actually works so i want to focus on that for now. However, any suggestions for the code in general are welcome :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *randomString(int minSize, int maxSize);
void printStrings(char **strArray, int strArraySize);

int main()
{
    int size, i;
    char **ptr;


    printf("Type in the number of characters you would like to be used: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    ptr = malloc(size*sizeof(ptr));
    if (ptr==NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory. The program will now terminate.");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        ptr[i] = randomString(5, 20);
    ptr[i] = '\0';

    puts(*ptr);


    return 0;



}


char *randomString(int minSize, int maxSize)
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    char *rndSize, *p;
    int i;
    rndSize = (char *)malloc(21);
    p = rndSize;
    for (i = minSize + rand() % 16; i<=maxSize && i>=minSize; i++)
        *p++ = 97 + rand() % 26;
  return rndSize;
}
```

Comment: You need to NUL terminate all your character buffers. `puts` (and all other string operations) requires it.

Comment: @kaylum could u please show me what you mean according to my code? I'm kind of new at this..

Comment: `malloc(21)`. There are many magic numbers like that in your code. Makes it hard to understand and maintain. Use symbolic names instead (`#define` or `const` variables for example). And you really should do error checking - for example, if `minSize` or `maxSize` is large then the code will get buffer overflows.

Comment: Increase `rndSize` `malloc` call by 1. then terminate at end of function with `rndSize[i] = '\0';`. "Strings" in C are NUL terminate character sequences (no native string type).

Comment: @kaylum minsize and maxsize are 5 and 20 and also the reason why i chose '21' is because every sequence must consist of 20 letters plus \0. So i guess it's correct. The compiler doesn't give me any errors or warnings.

Comment: There are MANY errors. 1) You are not freeing char arrays in the end of main. 2) your string are not null-terminated. You are setting '\0' only on last ptr element... but that's a char*, not a char! 3) each string malloced in randomString () should be terminated after the loop of rands. 4) you try to print only first string, but it is not null terminated, so you will go beyond random chars limit. 5) why malloc 21? What if maxSize is bigger? 6) the print before scanf asks for *chars to be used*. So only one string was the goal?

Comment: @Giannis It's good that there are no warnings. But that doesn't mean there aren't any errors (there are many). Allocating extra space is the first step. How about NUL terminate like I said? `malloc` does not zero memory for you. I see you tried `ptr[i] = '\0';`. But that is very wrong. `i` is `size` at that point which means it overflows the buffer and anyway, that only attempts to NUL terminate one of the strings, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *randomString(int minSize, int maxSize);
void printStrings(char **strArray, int strArraySize);

int main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int size, i;
    char **ptr;


    printf("Type in the number of characters you would like to be used: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    ptr = malloc(size*sizeof(*ptr));
    if (ptr==NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory. The program will now terminate.");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = randomString(5, 20);
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}


char *randomString(int minSize, int maxSize)
{
    char *rndSize, *p;
    int i;
    rndSize = (char *)malloc(maxSize+1);
    p = rndSize;
    for (i = minSize + rand() % 16; i<=maxSize; i++)
        *p++ = 97 + rand() % 26;
    *p = '\0';
  return rndSize;
}
```

It adds the NUL terminate character after each sequence. It also print each sequences one after the other. The random number generator initialization has been placed in the main to avoid getting the same sequence each time. It still looks strange to me that `t` is not initialized. There are still a lot of fix/improvements.

Comment: @Jona I accepted it but my upvote can't show cause i am new here. I'd like to ask you for a clarification. Since ptr is a pointer to a pointer,  using puts(ptr[i]) isn't supposed to print the content stored in the address thats pointed? which in this case in another address.

Comment: The declaration of `puts` is `int puts(const char *str)`. `puts` requires a pointer as parameter (and will write the value pointed to stdout).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
char *randomString(int minSize, int maxSize)
(...)
rndSize = (char *)malloc(21);
memset (rndSize , 0, 21*sizeof(char));
(...)
```

Regards.

Luis